# php laravel SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[image]

Anyone can help me ?

I waited for the problem to be solved [image]

Comment: Can i see `continuous_war_infos` migration file?

Comment: there are have  please click enter image description

Comment: Rather than ```$table->increments('id')```. Try this ```$table->id()```

Comment: i will try one minute

Comment: I have error doesnt work

Comment: @Siyami You would have to delete the previous migrations for that table and migrate again. Did you do that?

Comment: yes I did. I deleted old version and update

Comment: I need to see more portions of your code to understand the issue. Are you comfortable with contacting me via mail from my profile?

Comment: I am new this platform. How can I do send mail ?

Answer (score 0):

You need you add to ID field either bigIncrements(), id() or nullable() methods. Here told you tried without any value for ID

Comment: ıd have increments attribute

Comment: please share your migration

Comment: there are have please click enter image description

Comment: change increments() with id() . Like this $table->id()

Comment: I have error doesnt work

Comment: what is your db schema? mysql or pgsql?

Comment: Schema::create('continuous_war_infos', function (Blueprint $table)  mysql